# Set image size from from rss feed

Tags: php, image, image-processing, rss

I have a rss feed where the image size is not set, like the image shows like ---

```
**hello.tv/imagecache/{size}/cloud/content-images**
```

So here if I replace it by 300x400 than it comes the image. So now how can I change the image size from rss feed before it saves in the database.

I am working on php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to replace {size} with the string '300x400' you could use something as simple as PHP's built in str_replace function.

```
$str = '**hello.tv/imagecache/{size}/cloud/content-images**'
$replacedStr = str_replace('{size}', '300x400', $str);
```

http://php.net/str_replace